# How to solve "Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric" error in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query gets data from two tables and join them to  give output as a single output. Subquery works without any error. But when i run the whole query i get an error like this.

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

This is my query

```
SELECT a.REF_NO + ' - '
       + (SELECT DISTINCT ( c.c_name )
          FROM   C_MASTER c,
                 A_MASTER a
          WHERE  a.c_no = c._NO) AS refer
FROM   [A_MASTER] a,
       [C_MASTER] c
WHERE  a.c_no = c._no
ORDER  BY a.REF_NO
```

REF_NO is numeric data type.

Comment: Show example data and desired results.

Comment: result should be like this =>  10001 - annual competition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select CAST(a.REF_NO AS VARCHAR(100))
        +' - '
        +(select distinct (c.c_name) from C_MASTER c, A_MASTER a
            where a.c_no=c._NO) as refer
from [A_MASTER] a, [C_MASTER] c
where a.c_no=c._no
order by a.REF_NO
```

Overall this looks like a sloppy query to me, but I can't improve upon it without more explanation about what you're trying to do, what you want your results to look like, and what your tables look like. Also, is there a reason you aren't using joins?

Comment: @Stam  when i do so i get an exception like this   "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'REF_NO'."

Comment: @user6592730 You need to add `REF_NO` as an alias to the column. You would have gotten the same error if  your original query worked - there is no `REF_NO` column.

Answer (score 1):

Try out with the below query. 
Use a join instead of separating tables with comma when writing queries.

```
 Select  distinct  cast(a.ref_no as VARCHAR(50))+'-'+c.c_name 
 from C_MASTER c
      Join A_MASTER a
                        On a.c_no=c._NO
```